# Bootstrap Footer Copyright and Social Media Icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is something I've been racking my brain for the past couple of hours and would like some information to help me solve this. With the following row I'm tryin gto figure out how I can do the following.

On a mobile device only put the 6 social media icons across the container on its own line to cover the the entire width of the viewport.

On a mobile device only I would also like to be able to put the copyright information onto its own line to cover the entire width of the viewport.

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row vcenter">
            <div class="pull-left col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy;2016 by Me</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-icon"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-icon"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-icon"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-icon"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-icon"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-icon"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use CSS media queries for various viewport sizes to achieve mobile or other viewport specific styling.** In the following I gave the parent div's of the copyright and the social icons an id. If you resize the browser to less than 400px, both should center-align.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   #copyright {
      text-align: center;
   }
   #social > div{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
   }
}
```

*Note:* Your copyright and social media divs already take up the entire width of the viewport thanks to the bootstrap classes. I don't why you mentioned that they should specifically be on their own line. You can also use the bootstrap viewport specific classes themselves to alter styling.

Another note, *I suggest you don't use floats or floating alignment techniques anymore*. Use something like **flexbox** to achieve the same effect. It's more reliable.
[Brilliant guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Didn't change anything when I view on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

On your first div inside row vcenter remove
     `col-lg-4 col-xs-12`
and replace it with `col-xs-6`

on the second div remove
    `col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-xs-12`
and replace with `col-xs-6`

Comment: Didn't change anything when I view on my phone.